# Issue with the same looped function running more than once when called by buttons in tkinter

Tags: function, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I have a program where a ball is moved around a screen by 8-way movement buttons, using this function:

```
def contMove(moving):
    global a
    global b  
    global X, Y
    if moving:
        a = a + X
        b = b + Y
        mover.place(x = a, y = b)
        a, b, X, Y = edgeBounce(a, b, X, Y)
        mover.place(x = a, y = b)
        mover.after(17, contMove, moving)
    else:            
        return
```

I have all the directions and base speeds worked out, but when I click each button to run the movement function, it runs a new function - and they stack, causing the speed of the ball to increase every time I click a button. Because the function is looped so that the ball moves infinitely, I have no way of stopping the previous subroutines and I don't know what to do.

Here's the code that places the buttons:

```
for i in range(8):
    direction = tkinter.Button(text = directSym[i], width = width[i], height = height[i], bg = colour[i], font="comic", cursor = "hand1", fg = textCol[i], command = lambda X = xPixels[i], Y = yPixels[i]: setXY(X, Y))
    direction.grid(row = gridY[i], column = gridX[i])
```

*1 setXY isn't really very important, it just turns X and Y from parameters to global variables, does some checks, then runs contMove()
*2 xPixels and yPixels are lists containing the respective directional X and Y appendments for each direction. All the other lists are just aesthetic stuff.

Comment: it would be interesting to see the definition of `mover`. It seems to be an object but I can't figure out of what class ... Did you define the class? How does the code of `mover.after()` look like? (funciton definition)

Comment: mover is a label that gets placed. It serves no other purpose than to move around. And Im not really sure why I put it before .after. Your reply doesn'ĝ

Comment: mover is a tknter Label that gets placed, no text, blue colour. It serves no other purpose than to move around. And I'm not really sure why you put it before .after. Actually, I think you may misunderstand what .after is. It's not a class or a subroutine, it's a tkinter thingy that makes a subroutine loop after a number of milliseconds

Comment: sorry I just didn't recognize `mover` as a `Label`-object